# Dupliframes not showing in group instance

Tags: dupli-groups

I am making a chain inside a group instance that needs to follow a animated bezeir. When I googled for a way to make a object follow a curve without deforming, I found dupliframes.

After getting my object to follow the curve nicely, I returned to my main layer where many instances of my chain where sprawled about. However, every instance only showed the original link, completely ignoring my duplivert settings.
[image: Notice the green outline]
Here it looks fine
[image: Now nothing shows]
Here only the first like shows.

Is this a blender bug, or am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround or a different way to array an object along a curve without deforming?